# Select column from multiple DataFrames based on same header prefix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that iterates over the rows of a `csv` for the `Age` column and if an age is negative, it will print the `Key` and the `Age` value to a text file.

```
def neg_check():
    results = []

    file_path = input('Enter file path: ')
    file_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding = 'utf-8')
    
    for index, row in file_data.iterrows():
        if row['Age'] < 0:
            results.append((row['Key'], row['Age']))
    with open('results.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write("\n".join(map(str, results)))   
        outfile.close()
```

In order to make this code repeatable, how can I modify it so it will iterate the rows if the column starts with "`Age`"? My files have many columns that start with "`Age`" but end differently. . I tried the following...

`if row.startswith['Age'] < 0:`

and

`if row[row.startswith('Age')] < 0:`

but it throws `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'startswith'` error.

## My csv files:

sample 1

```
Key   Sex     Age
    1        Male          46
    2        Female        34
```

sample 2

```
Key   Sex     AgeLast
    1        Male          46
    2        Female        34
```

sample 3

```
Key   Sex     AgeFirst
    1        Male          46
    2        Female        34
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this in one step, but there are a few options. One is `filter`:

```
v = df[df.filter(like='AgeAt').iloc[:, 0] < 0]
```

Or,

```
c = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('AgeAt')][0]
v = df[df[c] < 0]
```

Finally, to write to CSV, use

```
if not v.empty:
    v.to_csv('invalid.csv')
```

Looping over your data is not necessary with pandas.

Comment: Works great, thanks @coldspeed! Can you explain what the `[0]` means in the first line or direct me to the documentation please?

Comment: @n8_ `df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('AgeAt')]` returns a list of (in your case) one column name. From this list, I extract the first element with `[0]`.

Comment: After some testing, this creates the file even if no negative ages were found (just writes headers). How can I modify to only write to file if negative ages are found? Using an if-statement returns: `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`